# python command not found on linux

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, bash, terminal

I have a problem while running python on linux, I have python3 already installed.

When type python3 on the terminal i got:

```
python 3.9.0
```

When I run any program I made with for example python I got this error

```
bash: python: command not found
```

And this happen to every python program I try to install on my machine.

Comment: Which Linux distribution are you using (abd which version of it) and how did you install Python?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Place the below line in ~/.bashrc file:

```
alias python=python3
```

After inserting run the below command:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

.bashrc is the configuration file for bash, a linux shell/command interpreter.
An alias is a substitute for a (complete) command. It can be thought of as a shortcut. By adding the above line, an alias is created for python3 in the name of python. Now the programs using python instead of python3 should work fine without any error.

Comment: python3 command is also not found so this is only helpful if there is python3

Answer (score 4):

I had the same error too with Ubuntu 20.04, in the case you like "python" to refer to "python3", you can simply install python-is-python3:

```
sudo apt-get install python-is-python3
```

After this, invoking python will work just fine

I verified this solution only with Ubuntu 20.04 (18.x has not this package)

Answer (score 4):

This error can be resolved, by simply linking.If you've got pytohn3 already installed, and still get the error "pytohn not found", try the below;

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python
```

This utomatically links and aliases python to python3

Answer (score 1):

Try `python3` instead of `python` when running python program.

For example:

```
python3 -m venv venv
```